# Time complexity and space complexity for beam search

Tags: algorithm, search, duplicates

I am making a study on deduplication with Trie.. In trie, storing the hash values of algorithm(eg-SHA1) and the lookup is done by beam search(say beam width n=2). Now my question what is the time and space complexity for the beam search and on what factor shall I make my heuristic function to choose the nodes. Since I am a basic learner about all these topics, please give your solutions for my doubt.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Space complexity is `beam_width * max_fanout` since these are the candidates you generate at each step. Then you need to get the max_fanout best options and repeat the process as many times as you want/can (depends on the height of the tree, or how deep you want to explore).

You can just sort the options and that will give you a  time complexity of:
 `O(depth * beam_width * max_fanout * Log(beam_width * max_fanout))`.

Or you can use the quickselect algorithm to identify the base max_fanout candidates, without sorting everything ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect)). This eliminates the log from the time complexity for a total of:  `O(depth * beam_width * max_fanout)`

Comment: You can use quickselect to select the top b elements in O(max_fanout) time, can't you? No need to completely sort them?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware of quickselect. Fixing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, by only keeping an array of 2 * beam_width and do quickselect housekeeping every beam_width steps (instead of every beam_width * max_fanout steps) you can get space complexity O(beam_width) instead of O(beam_width * max_fanout), while still enjoying time complexity O(depth * beam_width * max_fanout).

How it works:
While traversing the search tree, the first beam_width positions in the array (of length 2*beam_width) are being filled up with the values as they come in. After each beam_width steps, a k'th element algorithm (or quickselect) is performed to make sure the largest beam_width values are in the second half of the array. That way we keep the largest beam_width elements in the second half of the array. Time complexity of the housekeeping step is linear (2 * beam_width). However, we only have to do that maintenance every beam_width steps, so amortized, we get complexity O(2), meaning, O(1) (remove the 2 because it is a constant).

Please see a lecture from MIT: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-046j-design-and-analysis-of-algorithms-spring-2015/resources/lecture-5-amortization-amortized-analysis/ where this amortization concept is being explained, and how it is being used for example in garbage collection or dynamically adjusting (doubling/halving) arrays.